# Javascript loop table row working with rowspan and tr

Tags: javascript

I have table that need to custom with my JS in loop.

Below is the demo. What I need the final result is like this:

[image]

Is there any trick how to achieve as my result needed?

```js
var jsonStr = {
  "data": [
    {
      "data2": [
        {
          "partNo": "ABC",
          "plan": "120"
        },
        {
          "partNo": "DEF",
          "plan": "50"
        }
      ],
      "lineID": "1"
    },
    {
      "data2": [
        {
          "partNo": "FAB",
          "plan": "75"
        }
      ],
      "lineID": "2"
    }
  ]
};

for(var i=0; i<jsonStr.data.length; i++) {
  var line = "LINE " + jsonStr.data[i].lineID;
  
  var element = `<tr><td>${line}</td></tr>`;

  $(".tbl1 tbody").append(element);
  
  for(var j=0; j<jsonStr.data[i].data2.length; j++) {
    var partNo = jsonStr.data[i].data2[j].partNo;
    
    //console.log(partNo);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="tbl1" border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>Line</th>
    <th>Part No.</th>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<p>
It should be like this:
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>Line</th>
    <th>Part No.</th>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">LINE 1</td>
      
      <td>ABC</td><tr>
      <td>DEF</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="1">LINE 2</td>
      
      <td>FAB</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an approach using `Array.forEach` over the `obj.data` property to feed a target table tbody using the `rowspan` strategy.

Each time a new entry is visited in the new array, a new row is created and is given a `rowspan` value equal to the number of elements in its own `data2` property array (partNo).

Then for each pf those, a new row is added, starting from the second one, holding the current partNo alone.

I didn't see you were using jQuery so I went for vanilla js. Anyway this is the MDN reference to the topics faced here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-rowspan

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

```js
var obj = {  
  "data": [
    { 
      "lineID": "1",
      "data2": [{"partNo": "ABC","plan": "120"},{"partNo": "DEF","plan": "50"}],      
    },
    {      
      "lineID": "2",
      "data2": [{"partNo": "FAB","plan": "75"}],    
    }
  ]
};

//target tbody
const tbody = document.querySelector('#tbl1 tbody');

//for each entry in obj.data
obj.data.forEach( entry => {  
  
  //create a new currentRow
  let currentRow = document.createElement('tr');
  
  //create a cell for the current line and append it to the currentRow
  const tdLine = document.createElement('td');
  tdLine.textContent = `LINE ${entry.lineID}`;
  if(entry.data2.length > 1)
    tdLine.setAttribute('rowspan', entry.data2.length);
  currentRow.append(tdLine);
      
  //for each partNo
  entry.data2.forEach( (part, i) => {
    //if the index of the current partNo is > 0, commit the currentRow and make a new one
    if(i > 0){
      tbody.append(currentRow);
      currentRow = document.createElement('tr');      
    }
    //create the cell for the current partNo and append it to the currentRow
    const tdPart = document.createElement('td');
    tdPart.textContent = part.partNo;
    currentRow.append(tdPart);    
  });
  
  //append the currentRow to the table
  tbody.append(currentRow);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tbl1" class="tbl1" border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>Line</th>
    <th>Part No.</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set rowspan for the first cell of first group based on data2 length. Then render rest of group's rows with single cell with data2.

```js
const jsonStr = {
    "data": [
        {
            "data2": [
                {
                    "partNo": "ABC",
                    "plan": "120"
                },
                {
                    "partNo": "DEF",
                    "plan": "50"
                }
            ],
            "lineID": "1"
        },
        {
            "data2": [
                {
                    "partNo": "FAB",
                    "plan": "75"
                }
            ],
            "lineID": "2"
        }
    ]
};

const tbody = $(".tbl1").find("tbody");
for(let i=0; i<jsonStr.data.length; i++) {
    const label = "LINE " + jsonStr.data[i].lineID;
    
    let tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tbody.append(tr);
    let td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = label;
    td.rowSpan = jsonStr.data[i].data2.length;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = jsonStr.data[i].data2[0].partNo;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    for(let j=1; j<jsonStr.data[i].data2.length; j++) {
        const partNo = jsonStr.data[i].data2[j].partNo;
        tr = document.createElement("tr");
        tbody.append(tr);
        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = partNo;
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tbl1">
     <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```